# Android 6 Permissions - managing foreign apps permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-package-managers

Using the package manager I can see what permissions foreign apps request. But is it possible to find out what permissions the user allows for other apps? And can you change the permissions of other apps from your application? These questions apply on non-rooted devices.

Comment: "And can you change the permissions of other apps from your application?" -- no.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a rooted device; the way I follow to manage permission require root privileges:

Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

```
        dos.writeBytes("pm revoke/grant " + packageName + " " + permissionName);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
```

Maybe studing android security architecture you will be cabable to find a way to solve the problem on non-rooted devices but you'll waste a lot of time.